# Bag of Words in scikit learn : np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to implement bag of words for one hot encoding of categorical text data using CountVectorizer with minimum degree of freedom as 3 using the following code:

```
text_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=3)
train_text_feature_onehotCoding = text_vectorizer.fit_transform(train_df['TEXT'])
train_text_features = text_vectorizer.get_feature_names()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
np.nan is an invalid document, expected byte or unicode string.
```

I tried removing the Null values using train_df['TEXT'].dropna(inplace = True) but getting the following warning"

```
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
  return self._update_inplace(result)
```

Comment: You could remove `NaN` from `Text` with [dropna](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html) -> `train_df['TEXT'].dropna()` Assuming that `train_df` is a `pandas` DataFrame.

Comment: @HenryEcker I tried this earlier as well but this doesn't resolve the issue.